# Delete duplicate/older program versions from openwith - Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

As you can see here
[image]

I have so older versions of for example visual studio code. But how to delete them to only show one version?

I tried [this](https://mac-how-to.gadgethacks.com/how-to/remove-duplicates-customize-open-with-menu-mac-os-x-0157100/) tutorial from gadgethacks which didnt work because it is probably from 2014.

Does anyone know a fix for this? I tried googling which didnt bring me any good results.

Comment: If those apps are on any mounted drives, then they will appear there.

Comment: they are not, i just updated visual studio code to a new version and the older one still appears

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the Launch Service Database? https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/